# No advertisement is shown from Admob

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I had an Google Admob account which was banned by any reason (for 30 days, and I've no goddamn idea why) probably for "watching" the interstitial which I cannot avoid.

I then had to create a new account on AdMob because I do not have the time to wait 30 days for this.

I also have my iOS application linked to Firebase (On my old gmail account) which is linked to my banned AdMob account.

I replaced my key in info.plist and googleService-info.plist
I changed the app unit ID.

```
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-MY-ID-is-here")
        let request = GADRequest()

        request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID]
        interstitial.load(request)
        interstitial.delegate = self
```

```
                                    if self.interstitial.isReady
                                    {
                                        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        print("Advertisement is not ready!")

                                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "History", sender: self)
                                    }
```

No ads is being displayed on the application, but why? Is it impossible to add advertisement to this right now? Even thought I changed my account?

The new account is NOT linked to the Firebase, does that matter?

I expect advertisement to show up but it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same situation but the ads started coming once I linked my app store application link to the ad mob account.

- Make sure you have configured correct AdmobId in the App delegate and adUnitID in the controller correctly.

Singin to AdMob account and navigate to the app setting and find 'App name & store link'. You can link your app link from there.

Comment: I should add the new version to App Store first, right?

Comment: Yes, you should upload your app to the app store and then link that app store link into admob account.

Comment: I'll accept this when app is published and if its working. (Uploading atm, wait a day or two)

Answer (score 0):

First you should always use test ads otherwise you could get banned. Second try your code using test ad unit IDs - then you can see if problem lies in your code or account. If test ads work then the problem is not in your code! If not then post all the code or check account.

One more thing make sure you didn’t link your app with old AdMob account?

Regarding previous answer new AdMob SDK 7.44.0 app id goes to info.plist not AppDelegate. What version are you using if newer the AppDelegate or other place in app should include

```
 GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Test ads works just as fine! So I guess the issue is somewhere else then

Comment: Just in case. Check my edited answer redarding SDK versions.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I only switched the ID, in info-plist swell. 

My old Admob account is linked to my firebase account and to App Store, does that matter? Since I cannot remove it when I can't login to the account :/ Can I?

Comment: I do not think that's the case righty now, since it always worked before. And testads works fine. (Everything worked 2 days ago) so I can't see thats the issue.

Comment: If you changed app id did you changed also the ad unit id?

Comment: When I created a new account on AdMob they give me both App ID and AD UNIT ID, and yes. They are both changed.

Comment: Next does your app has old Apple bundle ID? The same id you linked app to your previous account?

Comment: I do have the same bundle id

Comment: I think this might be the problem. Just for testing try changing bundle id.

Comment: I cannot see that the bundle ID might be the problem, do you think so? Otherwise I'll have to re-upload it. Lets try

Comment: I think it might be the problem as it is linked to your old AdMob account.

Comment: What sdk are you using 7.44.0?

Comment: I just tested my interstitial ads are displaying fine with the code! Perhaps your ads are not yet loaded! Have you checked are your interstitial even loaded?

Comment: how can I check that? If its loading?

Comment: print(interstitial.isReady)